# 'couldnt execute menu item internal error [elisterror] index de liste hors limites 50'

Tags: wamp64

my wamp server icon is brown when i try installing apache services it brings this error message 'couldnt execute menu item internal error [elisterror] index de liste hors limites 50'

I tried changing port numbers, installing apache services and restarting all services

I EVEN INSTALLED VISUAL C++ REDISTRIBUTABLE THINKING ITS THE SOURCE OF THE CODE